# How to send an Object through a constructor?

Tags: java, object, constructor

I am currently facing a problem and can't find the way. Here is the question...

**Complete the Point class bellow:**

```
public class Point{
  private int x;
  private int y;
  public Point(int x, int y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
}
```

**So that the following code produces the output bellow:**

```
public class TestClass{
  public static void testEqual(Point p1, Point p2){
    if (p1.equals(p2)){
      System.out.println("The two points are equal\n"+p1);
    }else{
      System.out.println("The two points are not equal");
      System.out.println("First Point: "+ p1);
      System.out.println("Second Point: " + p2);
    }
  }
  public static void main(String [] args){
    Point p1 = new Point(2,3);
    Point p2 = Point.clonePoint(p1);
    Point p3 = new Point(1,1);
    Point p4 = new Point(2,3);
    testEqual(p1,p2);
    testEqual(p1,p3);
    testEqual(p1,p4);
    testEqual(p2,p4);
  }
}
```

**Outputs**

```
The two points are equal
The X Coordinate is 2 and the Y Coordinate is 3
The two points are not equal
First Point: The X Coordinate is 2 and the Y Coordinate is 3
Second Point: The X Coordinate is 1 and the Y Coordinate is 1
The two points are equal
The X Coordinate is 2 and the Y Coordinate is 3
The two points are equal
The X Coordinate is 2 and the Y Coordinate is 3
```

I can understand all the things but except this line `Point p2 = Point.clonePoint(p1);`
How can I solve it?

Comment: You are looking at static methods, not constructors.

Comment: `return new Point(p.x, p.y);`

Comment: solve what? the class Point has an static method at level class that returns a Point

Comment: @nachokk "Complete the class below"

Answer (score 0):

I think your homework wants you to add a [cloning method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clone_%28Java_method%29) to the `Point` class like this:

```
public class Point{
  private int x;
  private int y;
  public Point(int x, int y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
  public static Point clonePoint(Point p){ return new Point(p.x,p.y); }
}
```

Comment: It should be a static method.

Comment: @Aggieboy 1 error found:
File: C:\Users\Tushar\TestClass.java  [line: 13]
Error: non-static method clonePoint(Point) cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: Wow my bad lol fixed.  I'm sure the other answers are what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Add `get` methods for returning the point coordinates to your `Point` class:

```
public int getX()
{
   return x;
}

public int getY()
{
   return y;
}
```

Then add the following `clonePoint()` static method to your `Point` class:

```
public static Point clonePoint(Point p)
{
   return new Point(p.getX(), p.getY());
}
```

Then add the following `equals()` method to your `Point` class:

```
public boolean equals(Point p)
{
   return (p.getX() == getX()) && (p.getY() == getY());
}
```

Comment: Since the class has access to the private members of its instances, the gets() are unnecessary.  Since they are public, it also may give unwanted access to the x and y members to other classes.

Comment: What's the harm in allowing public access to the coordinates? The `Point` class is useless to any other classes otherwise.

Comment: Well they were initially defined as private, so I assumed there was some reason for it.  Otherwise, they should have been declared public in the first place XD

Comment: It's considered bad design to have class members public. This is why `get` methods are required.

Answer (score 0):

This is all you need:

*[note the last method 'clone' is a static (class) method that you access by prefixing it with the class name 'Point' followed by '.'].*

```
public class Point {

    private int x;
    private int y;

    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "The X Coordinate is " + x + " and the Y Coordinate is " + y;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object otherPoint) {
        if (this == otherPoint) return true;
        if (otherPoint == null || getClass() != otherPoint.getClass()) return false;

        Point point = (Point) otherPoint;

        return x == point.x && y == point.y;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = x;
        result = 31 * result + y;
        return result;
    }

    public static Point clonePoint(Point p) {
        return p != null ? new Point(p.x, p.y) : null;
    }
}
```